# The option "Pay with credit or debit card" is not displayed

Tags: paypal

When i use the Order API to create orders, in sandbox, and i retrieve and display the approval link, i can either log in to Paypal or open an account to make the payment. But when using the Paypal Buttons checkout example, the "open an account" option is replaced by "Pay with a credit and debit card", which is what i want. I don't find the way to have that option, using the create order API. Do you know what am i missing? I think the solution will be with application_context event, but i am running out of options.
Thanks

My payload:

```
{
    payer: {
      email_address: 'valid email',
      name: { given_name: 'Georges', surname: 'K' },
      address: {
        address_line_1: 'address',
        address_line_2: '',
        postal_code: '12345',
        country_code: 'CA',
        admin_area_1: '',
        admin_area_2: ''
      }
    },
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {...},
        payee: {...},
        description: 'Order'
      }
    ],
    application_context: {
      brand_name: 'Shop name',
      landing_page: 'BILLING',
      user_action: 'PAY_NOW',
      shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
      payment_method: { payee_preferred: 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED' },
      return_url: 'https://some_url',
      cancel_url: 'https://url'
    },
    intent: 'CAPTURE'
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a PayPal checkout, there are always two options.  The first option is to log into an existing account.

The second option will either say 'Create an Account' or 'Pay with a debit or credit card', but it's functionality is very similar either way. Sometimes paying as a guest is permitted, sometimes it is not. You can disable paying as a guest within the PayPal Checkout, but you cannot force it to be available.

To always have an option for Debit and Credit Cards, you need to put the black button for it on your site. This button can be connected to your server to create and capture orders via the API. See [this demo code sample](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) -- and for related information look for bullet #5 within [the Integrate Checkout guide.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addpaymentbuttons)

---

Incidentally, redirecting away from your site and then back to a return_url is an old integration method, for old web sites. The JS SDK's in-context / mini window approval flow is a much better user experience.  And, having the 'Debit or Credit Card' button expand within your own site is also quite a nice improvement.

Comment: In fact, i am building a mobile e-commerce app with Flutter, and i found the solution with the direct call to the API not perfect, but easy and convenient for a beginning. I will implement another solution then. Thanks

Comment: Web checkout buttons be used on mobile as long as they're in a view with an address bar (Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tabs, https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applicationss ). There is also a Native Checkout SDK.